# One View bind to different data models at different time (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-view

I have created a view (A HTML file consisting of some divs and input boxes) and now I want to use that file as a view at different places but with different data models binded to it.
"I mean change in ng-model of input tags"

One way is to make same view again and again and bind it with respective data model. But I don't want it..
How can I use only one HTML file as a view and bind it with different model at different place?

P.S : I am somewhat new to Angular-JS

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *use that file as a view at different places but with different data models* but in many cases a html file can be used as a template

Comment: "I mean change in ng-model of input tags "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean useing different controllers with the same html template? If your using `ngRoute` you could set it up like this

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/route1', {
    templateUrl: 'myView.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl1'
  }),
  when('/route2', {
    templateUrl: 'myView.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl2'
  });
```

Here is a tutorial on setting up routing: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: With this can I operate on say array1 with myCtrl1 and array2 with Ctrl2? I think I can but to be sure...